# Hadoop Input Formats - Usage

Tags: hadoop, avro

I know different file formats in Hadoop ? By default hadoop uses text input format. what is advantage/disadvantage of using text input format. 
What is advantage/disadvantage of avro over text input format.

Also please help me understand use case for different file formats(Avro, Sequence, TextInput, RCFile ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there are no advantages of Text as default other than its contents are human readable and friendly. You could easily view contents by issuing **Hadoop fs -cat** .

The disadvantages with Text format are

- It takes more resources on disk, so would impact the production job efficiency.
- Writing/Parsing the text records take more time
- No option to maintain data types incase the text is composed from multiple columns.

The Sequence , Avro , RCFile format have very significant advantages over Text format.

**Sequence** - The key/value objects are directly stored in the binary format through the Hadoop's native serialization process by implementing Writable interface. The data types of the columns are very well maintained, and parsing the records with relevant data type also done easily. Obvoiusly it takes lesser space compared with Text due to the binary format.

**Avro** -  Its a very compact binary storage format for hadoop key/value pairs, Reads/writes records through Avro serialization/deserialization. It is very similar to Sequence file format but also provides Language interoperability and cell versioning.

You may choose Avro over Sequence only if u need cell versioning or the data to be stored will used by few other applications written in different languages other than Java.Avro files can be processed by any languages like C, Ruby, Python, PHP, Java wherein Sequence files are specific only for Java.

**RCFile** - The Record Columnar File format is column oriented and it is a Hive specific storage format designed to make hive to support faster data load, reduce storage space.

Apart from this you may also consider the ORC and the Parquet file formats.

Comment: The other disadvantage of a text format is a lack of any scheme.